# Issue with running Unit Test in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I am getting the following error while building unit-test.

```
Error: "IUnitTestStorage.Open should be called before operation can continue."
```

I have never got this error before and all was working fine before this moment.

I have tried deleting all bin and obj files and rebuillding, it didn't help. Moreover, when I created new unit-test project (with no code of mine) and it gives the same error.

Closing all Visual Studio instances and starting them back didn't help as well.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Premium Update 4.

Answer (score 4):

I just closed and re-opened VS2015 and cleaned solution and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I got it today in Visual Studio 2015. Just delete all in debug folder, release folder and all in obj folder.

Build the solution then it works out.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48fae82e-2c71-40d1-aed2-f9b81ff8d477/anyone-help-with-this-error-iunitteststorageopen-should-be-called-before-operation-can-continue?forum=vsunittest) it helps to clean and rebuild solution, not just build. I know it's little bit silly but in case you haven't tried it...

Comment: I tried re-build. clean bin's and obj's. Its not of help. Same code works fine on another machine, but not this. Even IT guys couldn't figure and sadly suggest format machine as solution :(

Comment: Here's an important gotcha related to build - clean - rebuild.  If you build your solution and get this error, then doing a clean - rebuild will not make it go away yet, you will still see the error during your clean and rebuild steps.  You need to restart Visual Studio and then do a clean - rebuild.  In other words, doing a simple Build is not your friend, and it will trap you into a cycle of grief.  Either do a clean - rebuild from the get go, or restart Visual Studio and do a clean - rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with Updated version of Telerik Test Studio. Try Re-installing Telerik Test Studio to Resolve this. It works for me.